# 500 Internal Server Error error in Webservice request

Tags: web-services, soap, weblogic12c, webservice-client

I have an existing jar which sends web-service request from one of our application server to another. Below is the code for sending the request

```
 public IUsbMessage executeOutboundRequest(IUsbMessage paramIUsbMessage)
  {
    IUsbMessage localIUsbMessage = UsbMessageFactory.createUbusMessage();
    try
    {
      LogManager.logDebug("ServiceProvider:- Enter executeOutboundRequest");
      Object[] arrayOfObject = (Object[])paramIUsbMessage.getPayload();
      NVPVO localNVPVO = (NVPVO)arrayOfObject[1];
      String str1 = (String)localNVPVO.getHashmap().get("endPointUrl");
      String str2 = (String)localNVPVO.getHashmap().get("respTag");
      String str3 = (String)localNVPVO.getHashmap().get("body");
      str3 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><FIXML xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.oracle.com/fixml AcctInq.xsd\" xmlns=\"http://www.oracle.com/fixml\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" + str3.trim();
      LogManager.logDebug("ServiceProvider:- RequestXMLMsg" + str3);
      MessageFactory localMessageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
      SOAPMessage localSOAPMessage1 = localMessageFactory.createMessage();

      SOAPFactory localSOAPFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
      SOAPBody localSOAPBody = localSOAPMessage1.getSOAPBody();
      SOAPElement localSOAPElement1 = localSOAPBody.addChildElement(localSOAPFactory.createName("executeService"));
      SOAPElement localSOAPElement2 = localSOAPElement1.addChildElement(localSOAPFactory.createName("arg_0_0"));
      localSOAPElement2.addTextNode(str3);
      localSOAPMessage1.saveChanges();

      localSOAPMessage1.writeTo(System.out);

      SOAPConnectionFactory localSOAPConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
      SOAPConnection localSOAPConnection = localSOAPConnectionFactory.createConnection();

      LogManager.logDebug("ServiceProvider:- endPointUrl" + str1);
      LogManager.logDebug("ServiceProvider:- respTag" + str2);
      URL localURL = new URL(str1);
      SOAPMessage localSOAPMessage2 = localSOAPConnection.call(localSOAPMessage1, localURL);

      DocumentBuilderFactory localDocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder localDocumentBuilder = localDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document localDocument = localDocumentBuilder.newDocument();

      Element localElement1 = null;
      Element localElement2 = null;
      Text localText = null;
      Element localElement3 = null;

      Iterator localIterator = localSOAPMessage2.getSOAPBody().getChildElements();
      Object localObject2;
      Object localObject3;
      while (localIterator.hasNext())
      {
        localObject1 = (SOAPElement)localIterator.next();
        localElement1 = localDocument.createElement(((SOAPElement)localObject1).getNodeName());
        localObject2 = ((SOAPElement)localObject1).getAttributes();
        Object localObject4;
        if (((NamedNodeMap)localObject2).getLength() > 0) {
          for (int i = 0; i < ((NamedNodeMap)localObject2).getLength(); i++)
          {
            localObject4 = ((NamedNodeMap)localObject2).item(i);
            localElement1.setAttribute(((Node)localObject4).getNodeName(), ((Node)localObject4).getNodeValue());
          }
        }
        localElement3 = localElement1;
        localObject3 = ((SOAPElement)localObject1).getChildElements();
        while (((Iterator)localObject3).hasNext())
        {
          localObject4 = (SOAPElement)((Iterator)localObject3).next();
          localElement1 = localDocument.createElement(((SOAPElement)localObject4).getNodeName());

          NamedNodeMap localNamedNodeMap = ((SOAPElement)localObject1).getAttributes();
          if (localNamedNodeMap.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < localNamedNodeMap.getLength(); j++)
            {
              Node localNode = localNamedNodeMap.item(j);
              localElement1.setAttribute(localNode.getNodeName(), localNode.getNodeValue());
            }
          }
          localElement2 = localElement1;
          localText = localDocument.createTextNode(((SOAPElement)localObject4).getValue());
          localElement2.appendChild(localText);
          localElement3.appendChild(localElement2);
        }
```

The data which is being passed to the class file is as below containing the request XML and other details

```
respTag=AcctInqRs,
body=<Header>
  <RequestHeader>
    <MessageKey>
      <RequestUUID>Req_159538426</RequestUUID>
      <ServiceRequestId>AcctInq</ServiceRequestId>
      <ServiceRequestVersion>10.2</ServiceRequestVersion>
      <ChannelId>OR</ChannelId>
      <LanguageId></LanguageId>
    </MessageKey>
    <RequestMessageInfo>
      <BankId>54</BankId>
      <TimeZone></TimeZone>
      <EntityId></EntityId>
      <EntityType></EntityType>
      <ArmCorrelationId></ArmCorrelationId>
      <MessageDateTime>2020-02-23T14:27:22.627</MessageDateTime> 
     </RequestMessageInfo>
     <Security>
       <Token>
         <PasswordToken>
           <UserId></UserId>
           <Password></Password>
         </PasswordToken>
       </Token>
       <FICertToken></FICertToken>
       <RealUserLoginSessionId></RealUserLoginSessionId>
       <RealUser></RealUser>
       <RealUserPwd></RealUserPwd>
       <SSOTransferToken></SSOTransferToken>
      </Security>
    </RequestHeader>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <AcctInqRequest>
      <AcctInqRq>
        <AcctId>
          <AcctId>1101614</AcctId>
        </AcctId>
      </AcctInqRq>
    </AcctInqRequest>
  </Body>
</FIXML>,
reqhdr.requestuuid=FINCORE240716215711,
endPointUrl=https://ORPREPROD.domain.com:20322/fiwebservice/FIWebService,
reqhdr.messagedatetime=2020-04-21T21:57:11.000,
reqhdr.servicerequestversion=10.2,
reqhdr.origchannelid=COR,
reqhdr.bankid=54,
reqhdr.servicerequestid=AcctInq
```

Now the issue is that the request is being sent from server A to server B. Once the request reaches server B it is throwing error "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" and the below xml is seen in the logs

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body>
<env:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>**Failed to get operation  name from incoming request**</faultstring>
</env:Fault>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

On both the servers our application is deployed on Weblogic and the above errors are from weblogic logs. Can anyone please help me to determine the exact cause of this error, I am totally stuck and clueless about what to do.

The same request XML when sent through SOAP UI works perfectly.

The below request XML works in SOAPUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:web="http://webservice.fiusb.ci.ibm.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:executeService>
         <arg_0_0><![CDATA[<FIXML xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.finacle.com/fixml AcctInq.xsd" xmlns="http://www.finacle.com/fixml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Header><RequestHeader><MessageKey><RequestUUID>Req_158495384262711</RequestUUID><ServiceRequestId>AcctInq</ServiceRequestId><ServiceRequestVersion>10.2</ServiceRequestVersion><ChannelId>COR</ChannelId><LanguageId></LanguageId></MessageKey><RequestMessageInfo><BankId>54</BankId><TimeZone></TimeZone><EntityId></EntityId><EntityType></EntityType><ArmCorrelationId></ArmCorrelationId><MessageDateTime>2020-02-23T14:27:22.627</MessageDateTime></RequestMessageInfo><Security><Token><PasswordToken><UserId></UserId><Password></Password></PasswordToken></Token><FICertToken></FICertToken><RealUserLoginSessionId></RealUserLoginSessionId><RealUser></RealUser><RealUserPwd></RealUserPwd><SSOTransferToken></SSOTransferToken></Security></RequestHeader></Header><Body><AcctInqRequest><AcctInqRq><AcctId><AcctId>1100161916154</AcctId></AcctId></AcctInqRq></AcctInqRequest></Body></FIXML>
]]></arg_0_0>
      </web:executeService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The below XML throws the same error "Failed to get operation  name from incoming request"

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:web="http://webservice.fiusb.ci.ibm.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:executeService>
         <arg_0_0><![CDATA[<FIXML xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.finacle.com/fixml AcctInq.xsd" xmlns="http://www.finacle.com/fixml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Header><RequestHeader><MessageKey><RequestUUID>Req_158495384262711</RequestUUID><ServiceRequestId>AcctInq</ServiceRequestId><ServiceRequestVersion>10.2</ServiceRequestVersion><ChannelId>COR</ChannelId><LanguageId></LanguageId></MessageKey><RequestMessageInfo><BankId>54</BankId><TimeZone></TimeZone><EntityId></EntityId><EntityType></EntityType><ArmCorrelationId></ArmCorrelationId><MessageDateTime>2020-02-23T14:27:22.627</MessageDateTime></RequestMessageInfo><Security><Token><PasswordToken><UserId></UserId><Password></Password></PasswordToken></Token><FICertToken></FICertToken><RealUserLoginSessionId></RealUserLoginSessionId><RealUser></RealUser><RealUserPwd></RealUserPwd><SSOTransferToken></SSOTransferToken></Security></RequestHeader></Header><Body><AcctInqRequest><AcctInqRq><AcctId><AcctId>1100161916154</AcctId></AcctId></AcctInqRq></AcctInqRequest></Body></FIXML>
]]></arg_0_0>
      </web:executeService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Notice the forward slash(/) at the end of namespace. If the slash is not there in the namespace it throws the error in SOAP UI.
Please help me to understand how can I change namespace in my java code

Comment: I've formated the part "data which is being passed", but the `body` is malformed. I can see that in your code you do add `<FIXML>` to the `body`, so it's **not really** malformed... but then I wonder - what else in the question is not inline with reality. So please update your question so that it can be more readable and **correct**

Comment: Also 1) "data which is being passed" is not as interesting as a raw request. Can you provide it? 2) `str2` (`respTag`) in your code is never used, but you enumerate it among the "data which is being passed" 3) the error reads `Failed to get operation name`... so what the expected name should be?

Comment: @x00 What could be the reason for "Failed to get operation code" ? I don't have any option to provide raw data

Comment: All of the above and much more. Including error on the other server (e.g error message can be misleading if you server requires credentials and you `body` obviously sends nothing of the sort). I can't add anything to what I already said, unless you provide more info.

Comment: @x00 in SOAP UI it throws the same error if forward slash is removed from namespace. Please let me know how can I make the namespace changes in my JAVA code.

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that web services are case-sensitive. Did you check on this ? I mean the method name in the request URL ?